# Getting data out of a firebase function in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

So the function gets all the children in my firebase server and then fuzzy searches it for my deviceID string. If its found it records the name of the child to the chat array and the last child sub-child to the message array. The problem is that when I print it its empty even though there should be data. I know its something with the self.chats.append line.

```
var chats = [String]()
var messages = [String]()
var deviceID = "asdadasdas"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://MYURL.firebaseio.com/")
    databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        //If a string is in the child name it adds the childname to an array and pulls a sub-child and adds it to another array
        for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            let stringg = rest.key as String
            if stringg.range(of:self.deviceID!) != nil {
                self.chats.append(stringg)
                let messagesQuery = databaseRef.child(stringg).queryLimited(toLast: 1)
                messagesQuery.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
                    if let data = snapshot.value as? [String : String] {
                        self.messages.append(data["text"]! as String)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    })




    print(messages)
    print(chats)
}
```

}

Comment: Please can you show us your database JSON? A screenshot should do

Comment: You need to understand what an asynchronous network call is.